# Nightmarejs proxy

Tags: javascript, proxy, nightmare

So I'm uising nightmare to generate scenarios of users using a page to get the HTTP-Requests of the page proxy-ed
To do so I'm using http-proxy and setting it like this :

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://localhost:9000', auth: 'test:test'}).listen(8000);
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('request successfully proxied!' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
  res.end();
}).listen(9000);
```

and then I use nightmare like this :

```
var nightmare = Nightmare({show: true,
        switches : {
            'proxy-server': 'localhost:9000;',
            'ignore-certificate-errors': true,
        }})
nightmare.authentication('test', 'test')
        .goto('http://localhost:4200/login')
        .type('#name', 'test'+user)
        .type('#pwd', 'test'+user)
        .click('#log')
        .wait('body')
```

but when I launch it, nightmare goes on the proxy (so localhost:9000) and ignores the goto(localhost:4200), can someone help me?

Comment: try replacing one or both localhost with 127.0.0.1